# How to remove bundle product from cart programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, bundled-product

I want to remove the bundle product from cart programmatically I am using

```
`$skunew="demobundle";
     $bundled_product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->loadByAttribute('sku',trim($skunew));
     $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $bundled_product_id) {
                $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();     
                break;
            }
        }`
```

In my cart **bundle product** **sku="demobundle-demoprod1-demoprod4-demoprod5"** give me some solution.how to remove or how to update this bundle.

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Does it not remove the item? Does it do something else? Do you get an error

Comment: @fschmengler  actually I am updating bundle product programmatically from cart and  adding it to cart but it is creating one more product with error message of some selections are missing.so want to remove the product from cart.

Comment: sounds like an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Instead of removing a product that you did not want to add in the first place it would be better to fix your code to not add this product.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$items = $cart->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $_item){
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());

   if($_product->getTypeId()=== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE){
       $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
       Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->removeItem($options['info_buyRequest']['product'])->save();
   }
}
```